A7670SA (LTE Module) + STM32 Send request to Spring Server
I have an arduino project that reads data collected from sensors (JSON) and sends it to a Spring Boot server on AWS, and everything worked fine. However, I've now created a new project in which I'm using an STM32L0 instead of an Arduino. Now, everything that the arduino's TinyGSM library used to do, I have to redo command by command, using the module's AT commands.
I've already managed to set up the GPRS PDP and now I need to make the requests. And that's where my problem lies.
I created a flow of commands that initiates the HTTP connection, connects to the server, sets the file type, sends and disconnects. But apparently something is going wrong.
When I start the program, it seems that the information runs over each other, and AT commands are arriving together with JSON on my server, which causes an error. You can see this in the attached image.

Exception: JsonParseException Unrecognized token 'AT' was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (String) "AT+HTTPACTION=1
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u00 00\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u 0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"; line: 1, column: 3]

In this image, the action command has reached the server, but sometimes other commands do too, or the json is mixed up with one of the commands.
I made the following system:
Setup:
int started = 0;

void setup() {
    DEBUG_PRINT("Starting...\r\n");

    // SX1276 compatible module connected to SPI1, NSS pin connected to GPIO with label LORA_NSS
    myLoRa = newLoRa();

    myLoRa.CS_port = NSS_GPIO_Port;
    myLoRa.CS_pin = NSS_Pin;
    myLoRa.reset_port = LORA_RST_GPIO_Port;
    myLoRa.reset_pin = LORA_RST_Pin;
    myLoRa.DIO0_port = DIO_GPIO_Port;
    myLoRa.DIO0_pin = DIO_Pin;
    myLoRa.hSPIx = &hspi1;

    myLoRa.frequency = 915;             // default = 433 MHz
    myLoRa.spredingFactor = SF_7;            // default = SF_7
    myLoRa.bandWidth = BW_250KHz;       // default = BW_125KHz
    myLoRa.crcRate = CR_4_8;          // default = CR_4_5
    myLoRa.power = POWER_17db;      // default = 20db
    myLoRa.overCurrentProtection = 130;             // default = 100 mA
    myLoRa.preamble = 10;              // default = 8;

    if (LoRa_init(&myLoRa) == LORA_OK) {
        DEBUG_PRINT("LoRa Ready\r\n");
    } else
        DEBUG_PRINT("Error in LoRa connection\r\n");

    if (FRAM_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_ERROR)
        DEBUG_PRINT("FRAM Ready\r\n");
    else
        DEBUG_PRINT("Error in FRAM connection\r\n");

    LoRa_startReceiving(&myLoRa);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DEBUG_LED_GPIO_Port, DEBUG_LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    I2C_Scan();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(K_GPIO_Port, K_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_Delay(100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(K_GPIO_Port, K_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(K_GPIO_Port, K_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    //HAL_Delay(1000);
    ///sendAT("+CRESET", "OK", 1);

    HAL_Delay(10000);

    DEBUG_PRINT("Send AT:\r\n");

    sendAT("", "OK", 1);
    modemStart(apn, user, pwd);

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    started = 1;
    DEBUG_PRINT("Started!\r\n");
}

void loop() {
    if (started >= 1) {
        HAL_Delay(1000);

        float dataPackage[] = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0};
        Transmission_VibrationPackage vibrationPackage = {
            .type = 'V',
            .key = "123456",
            .axis = 0,
            .dataPackage = {0},
            .start = 0,
            .end = 9
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < TRANSMISSION_DATA_PACKAGE; i++) {
            vibrationPackage.dataPackage[i] = dataPackage[i];
        }

        char* vibrationJSON = generateTransmissionVibrationPackageJSON(&vibrationPackage);
        sendHTTPPost(vibrationJSON);
        free(vibrationJSON);
    }
}

char* generateTransmissionDataJSON(Transmission_Data* data) {
    char *json = (char*) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    if (json == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    snprintf(json, 256,
            "{\"type\":\"%s\",\"key\":\"%s\",\"rmsAccel\":[%.2f,%.2f,%.2f],\"rmsVel\":[%.2f,%.2f,%.2f],\"temperature\":%.2f,\"battery\":%.2f}",
            data->type, data->key, data->rms_accel[0], data->rms_accel[1],
            data->rms_accel[2], data->rms_vel[0], data->rms_vel[1],
            data->rms_vel[2], data->temperature, data->battery);

    return json;
}

char* generateTransmissionVibrationPackageJSON(Transmission_VibrationPackage* package) {
    int size = 256 + (package->end - package->start + 1) * 20;
    char* json = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    if (json == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    snprintf(json, size, "{\"type\":\"%c\",\"key\":\"%s\",\"axis\":%d,\"dataPackage\":[",
             package->type, package->key, package->axis);

    for (int i = package->start; i <= package->end; i++) {
        char buffer[20];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%.2f", package->dataPackage[i]);
        strcat(json, buffer);

        if (i < package->end) {
            strcat(json, ",");
        }
    }

    snprintf(json + strlen(json), size - strlen(json), "],\"start\":%d,\"end\":%d}",
             package->start, package->end);

    return json;
}

AT commands sent to the module using interrupts and buffers:
typedef enum {
    FREE = 0, WAITING = 1, RX = 2, PROCESSING = 3
} GSMStatus;

uint8_t Rx_buffer[100];
uint8_t Rx_data = 0;
int rx_index = 0;

uint16_t lastRxTick = 0;

GSMStatus gsmStatus = FREE;

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
    if (huart->Instance == huart1.Instance) {

    }
    if (huart->Instance == huart2.Instance) {
        GSM_RX_Callback();
    }
}

uint16_t sendTick = 0;
void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
    if (huart->Instance == huart1.Instance) {

    }
    if (huart->Instance == huart2.Instance) {
        GSM_TX_Callback();
    }
}

void GSM_RX_Callback() {
    Rx_buffer[rx_index++] = Rx_data;
    lastRxTick = HAL_GetTick();
    gsmStatus = RX;
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &Rx_data, 1);
}

void GSM_TX_Callback() {
    if (gsmStatus == FREE) {
        gsmStatus = WAITING;
        sendTick = HAL_GetTick();
    }
}

void resetBuffers() {
    Rx_data = 0;
    rx_index = 0;
    memset(Rx_buffer, 0, sizeof(Rx_buffer));
}

char* sendAT(char command[], char answer[], int waitForAnswer) {
    char ATcommand[200];
    uint8_t commandBuffer[200] = { 0 };
    uint8_t ATisOK = 0;
    sendTick = HAL_GetTick();
    uint8_t rx_answer[100];

    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &Rx_data, 1);

    snprintf(ATcommand, sizeof(ATcommand), "AT%s\r\n", command);

    memcpy(commandBuffer, (uint8_t*) ATcommand, strlen(ATcommand) + 1);

    DEBUG_PRINT("Sending AT Command: \r\n");
    DEBUG_PRINT(ATcommand);

    HAL_Delay(100);

    int retries = 0;

    while (!ATisOK) {
        if (gsmStatus == FREE) {
            HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, commandBuffer, sizeof(commandBuffer));
        }

        if (gsmStatus == PROCESSING) {
            rx_answer[sizeof(rx_answer) - 1] = '\0';

            ATisOK = !waitForAnswer;

            if (strstr((char*) rx_answer, answer)) {
                resetBuffers();
                ATisOK = 1;
                break;
            }

            if (strstr((char*) rx_answer, "ERROR")) {
                if (waitForAnswer == 1) {

                    if (retries >= 10) {
                        //DEBUG_PRINT("Erro ao enviar o comando AT: \r\n");
                        resetBuffers();
                        ATisOK = 1;
                        break;
                    }

                    gsmStatus = FREE;
                    retries++;
                    HAL_Delay(200);
                } else {
                    resetBuffers();
                    ATisOK = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            memset(rx_answer, 0, sizeof(rx_answer));
            HAL_Delay(100);
            gsmStatus = FREE;
        }

        if (gsmStatus >= WAITING) {

            if (gsmStatus == RX) {
                if (HAL_GetTick() >= lastRxTick + 100) {
                    memcpy(rx_answer, Rx_buffer, sizeof(Rx_buffer));
                    retries = 0;
                    rx_index = 0;
                    memset(Rx_buffer, 0, sizeof(Rx_buffer));
                    gsmStatus = PROCESSING;
                }
            }
            if (gsmStatus != PROCESSING) {
                if (HAL_GetTick() >= sendTick + 20000) {
                    DEBUG_PRINT("TimeOut\r\n");
                    resetBuffers();
                    gsmStatus = FREE;

                    if (retries >= 2) {
                        resetBuffers();
                        break;
                    }
                    retries ++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    resetBuffers();

    gsmStatus = FREE;

    char *returnBuffer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(returnBuffer, (char*) rx_answer, 100);

    DEBUG_PRINT("GSM answer: \r\n");
    char ATanswer[200];
    sprintf(ATanswer, "%s\r\n", returnBuffer);
    DEBUG_PRINT(ATanswer);

    return returnBuffer;
}

GPRS and Starting Modem:
void modemStart(char *apn, char *user, char *pwd) {
    free(sendAT("", "OK", 1));

    free(sendAT("+CPIN?", "OK", 1));

    free(sendAT("+CREG?", "OK", 1));

    free(sendAT("+CSQ", "OK", 1));

    char command[200];

    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "+CGAUTH=1,1,\"%s\",\"%s\"", user, pwd);
    free(sendAT(command, "OK", 1));
    memset(command, 0, sizeof(command));

    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"%s\"", apn);
    free(sendAT(command, "OK", 1));
    memset(command, 0, sizeof(command));

    free(sendAT("+CGACT=1,1", "OK", 1));

    free(sendAT("+CGATT?", "OK", 1));
}

Requests:
char* sendHTTPGet() {
    free(sendAT("+HTTPINIT", "OK", 1));
    free(
            sendAT(
                    "+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://ec2-54-212-246-25.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/data/test\"",
                    "OK", 1));
    free(sendAT("+HTTPACTION=0", "OK", 1));
    char *read = (sendAT("+HTTPREAD", "OK", 1));
    free(sendAT("+HTTPTERM", "OK", 1));

    char *returnBuffer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(returnBuffer, read, 100);
    free(read);
    return returnBuffer;
}

char* sendHTTPPost(char *json) {
    int length = strlen(json);
    uint8_t *jsonAsUint8 = malloc(length);

    if (jsonAsUint8 == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    memcpy(jsonAsUint8, (uint8_t*) json, length);

    free(sendAT("+HTTPINIT", "OK", 1));

    HAL_Delay(250);
    free(
            sendAT(
                    "+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://ec2-54-212-246-25.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/data/register\"",
                    "OK", 1)
    );

    HAL_Delay(250);
    free(sendAT("+HTTPPARA=\"CONTENT\",\"application/json\"", "OK", 1));

    HAL_Delay(250);

    char command[200];
    sprintf(command, "+HTTPDATA=%d,10000\r\n", length);
    DEBUG_PRINT(command);
    free(sendAT(command, "DOWNLOAD", 1));

    HAL_Delay(500);
    gsmStatus = WAITING;

    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, jsonAsUint8, length, 2000);

    HAL_Delay(100);

    resetBuffers();
    gsmStatus = FREE;

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    free(sendAT("+HTTPACTION=1", "OK", 1));
    HAL_Delay(250);
    char *read = (sendAT("+HTTPREAD", "OK", 1));
    HAL_Delay(250);
    free(sendAT("+HTTPTERM", "OK", 1));

    char *returnBuffer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(returnBuffer, read, 100);
    free(read);
    return returnBuffer;
}

These codes form my data sending system.
Given this general context of how I'm dealing with commands and initialization, we can get to the error.
It's probably in the way I'm sending the json data to my module in "sendHTTPPost"


Instead of dumping nearly 400-line of code, and saying "apparently something is going wrong", it would be better to test each function to make sure it works as expected first. 2) Focus on generateTransmissionDataJSON(), generateTransmissionVibrationPackageJSON() and sendHTTPPost(), the rest code that you shown are irrelevant to the error message.


Instead of trying to write your own parser, it would be better to use the TinyGSM module, your STML0 can be run as Arduino code if you install STM's official stm32duino core for Arduino.

I fixed the problem by correcting the way the json data is sent to the module, and then I put in a restriction so that it knows it can proceed with the other commands.
